# ModuleNotFoundError in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to Python.

If I run the command

**>>>import requests**

in Wing Ide.

I get error.

**Error:**
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\untitled-1.py", line 1, in 
import requests

**builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'**

So I changed the IDE to Spyder.

this time that IDE could run "requests" but my second command line I wrote
**>>> from bs4 import beautifulSoup**

This time I get another error.

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'**

Why do I get these errors?

My computer is Win 10 - i7
I have downloaded Python 3.
In my computer several architectural programs is downloaded like Autodesk Revit. I have heard that it uses Python 2. So maybe the problem is this. But in another computer (samecoputer: Win 10- python 3) I deleted Revit but I still get the same error. So probably I do something wrong.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: These modules are not part of the standard library, so you have to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install bs4 and requests. A good way to do this is to install them from the terminal.

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4

pip3 install requests
```

Comment: Thank you I will search for terminal installing.